# Regex to match second repeated words in a string using R

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, stringr

I have the following vector of strings and I need to match the second repeated words, not the first ones,
without spaces.

```
names_vec <- c("Linda Smith","Elizabeth Olsen Green Elizabeth Olsen Green",
"Eva Ferguson","Charlize Martinez White Charlize Martinez White",
"digital copy solutions digitals",
"honor security services honor")
```

The resulting vector should be:
Edited desired Answer , my mistake there is a misunderstanding. When matching the second duplicate in "honor security services honor" the last
word is the one which has to be matched and removed.

```
matched_vec <- c("Elizabeth Olsen Green","Charlize Martinez White","honor security services")
```

I have tried different lookarounds but have been unsuccessful. The following code matches the first occurrences but I need the last ones because I want to remove the last repeated words not the first ones.

The code below grabs what is inside the brackets, I want the other repeated words.

```
str_view_all(names_vec , "(\\b\\S+\\s*\\b)(?=.*\\b\\1\\b)", match = TRUE)

[Elizabeth Olsen Green] Elizabeth Olsen Green 
[Charlize Martinez White] Charlize Martinez White
[honor] security services honor
```

The regex I used matches The FIRST repeated words of every string that have duplicates from the beginning of the string.

My expectation is to match the SECOND repeated words of the strings, so it has to search from the right to the left and match all of the second repeated words.

People will ask me, why bother. The issue is that I have some company names, and usually the repeated word I want to remove is the second one or the last one if you count from the left to the right.

Comment: Perhaps using a second capture group for the last occurrence `\b(\w(?:.*\w)?)\b.*\b(\1)\b` See https://regex101.com/r/OK7Jw0/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `stringi::stri_reverse` to reverse the characters. Then I use your regex in `gsub` and remove the *first repetition*, what is actually the last repetition, and reverse the result again.

```
stringi::stri_reverse(
           gsub("(\\b\\S+\\s*\\b)(?=.*\\b\\1\\b)", "",
                stringi::stri_reverse(names_vec), perl=TRUE) )
#[1] "Linda Smith"                     "Elizabeth Olsen Green "         
#[3] "Eva Ferguson"                    "Charlize Martinez White "       
#[5] "digital copy solutions digitals" "honor security services "
```

Or just using `sub`:

```
sub("(\\b\\S.*\\b)(.*)\\b\\1\\b", "\\1\\2", names_vec)
#[1] "Linda Smith"                     "Elizabeth Olsen Green "         
#[3] "Eva Ferguson"                    "Charlize Martinez White "       
#[5] "digital copy solutions digitals" "honor security services "
```

Comment: thank you for your response  , your answer so far is the most helpful answer, Also is there any way I can use just tidyverse to get the same result ?

Comment: I don't know if there is a stri_reverse also in stringr / tidyverse. `gsub` from *base* is not disabled when activating tidyverse, so it will work there. Changing the syntax by using pipes will not change the result, so yes if needed this will be possible.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to be a compact `stringr` solution:

```
str_remove(names_vec, "(.*).*(?=\\b\\1\\b)")
[1] ""   "Elizabeth Olsen Green"   ""   "Charlize Martinez White"   ""   "honor"
```

Here, we remove anything that is repeated as well as anything that follows, thus keeping only the actual repeat, or duplicate, itself. To identify the dupe we use a positive look-ahead `(?=...)` and a backreference `\\1` wrapped into word `\\b`oundaries.

If you don't want the empty strings, remove them by subsetting:

```
matched_vec <- str_remove(names_vec, "(.*).*(?=\\b\\1\\b)")
matched_vec[matched_vec != ""]
[1] "Elizabeth Olsen Green"   "Charlize Martinez White" "honor"
```

Alternatively, consider a `tidyverse` solution:

```
data.frame(names_vec) %>%
  extract(names_vec, into = c("1st","2nd"), "(.*).*(\\b\\1\\b)", remove = FALSE) %>%
  select(-"1st")
                                        names_vec                     2nd
1                                     Linda Smith                        
2     Elizabeth Olsen Green Elizabeth Olsen Green   Elizabeth Olsen Green
3                                    Eva Ferguson                        
4 Charlize Martinez White Charlize Martinez White Charlize Martinez White
5                 digital copy solutions digitals                        
6                   honor security services honor                   honor
```

Here we use `tidyr`'s function `extract` to partition the strings into two capture groups, one for the `1st` part, one for the `2nd` part, which is the repetition of the `1st`; what is *repeated* is identified by the backreference `\\1`

Comment: thank you for your response , quite complete. Sorry for the misunderstanding is the first time I ask here. The desired answer for the vector is c("Elizabeth Olsen Green","Charlize Martinez White","honor security services"). That is why I need to match the second duplicate in order to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach that can be considered

```
library(stringr)

str_view_all_Mod <- function(string, pattern, match = NA) 
{
  if(identical(match, TRUE)) {
    string <- string[str_detect(string, pattern)]
  }
  else if (identical(match, FALSE)) {
    string <- string[!str_detect(string, pattern)]
  }
  loc <- str_locate_all(string, pattern)
  string_list <- Map(loc = loc, string = string, function(loc, 
                                                          string) {
    if (nrow(loc) == 0) 
      return(string)
    for (i in rev(seq_len(nrow(loc)))) {
      str_sub(string, loc[i, , drop = FALSE]) <- paste0(" /// ", 
  str_sub(string, loc[i, , drop = FALSE]), " /// ")
    }
    string
  })
  string <- unlist(string_list)
  string <- str_remove_all(string, pattern = "///  ///")
  return(string)
}

reverse_String <- function(text)
{
  splits <- strsplit(text, "")[[1]]
  reversed <- rev(splits)
  final_result <- paste(reversed, collapse = "")
  return(final_result)
}

names_vec <- c("Linda Smith","Elizabeth Olsen Green Elizabeth Olsen Green Allo bonjour Elizabeth Olsen Green",
               "Eva Ferguson","Charlize Martinez White Charlize Martinez White",
               "digital copy solutions digitals",
               "honor security services honor")

nb_Text <- length(names_vec)
names_vec_rev <- rep(NA, nb_Text)

for(i in 1 : nb_Text)
{
  names_vec_rev[i] <- reverse_String(names_vec[i])
}

text <- str_view_all_Mod(names_vec_rev, "(\\b\\S+\\s*\\b)(?=.*\\b\\1\\b)", match = TRUE)
text <- stringr::str_extract(text, "///[^/]*///")
text <- stringr::str_remove_all(text, "///")
text <- lapply(X = text, FUN = reverse_String)
unlist(text)


[1] " Elizabeth   Olsen   Green "   " Charlize   Martinez   White " " honor "
```

Comment: thank you for your response , quite complete. Sorry for the misunderstanding is the first time I ask here. The desired answer for the vector is c("Elizabeth Olsen Green","Charlize Martinez White","honor security services"). That is why I need to match the second duplicate in order to remove them.